# Tkinter Listbox width interferes with scrollbars

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, scrollbars

I've got an issue where I've got a scrollbox displaying a few rows each row is about 200 characters wide. I had the width set to 125 which wasn't enough. However when I bump it past about 175 my scroll bars disappear. If I have it at or below 100 it scrolls through all the data but is a very small window. I would like the window to be the size of the frame and scroll through all the code.
Code:

---

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
def view():
    data = ['|unique_id |     id |              species | sex_age |  collector |                          location |                  preparator | collection_date | entered_date | innitials |         notes', 
            '|       88 | A-1444 |      puffinus grseus |     n/a |        n/a |                               n/a |                         n/a |     13 May 2013 |  27 Apr 2017 |        EB | TL: 395mm WC:',
            '|       72 | A-1444 |      puffinus grseus |     n/a |        n/a |                               n/a |                         n/a |     13 May 2013 |  27 Apr 2017 |        EB | TL: 395mm WC:',
            '|       71 | A-1445 |        anas clypeata |       M |  G. Webber |                               n/a |                     A. Zack |     23 Oct 2013 |  26 Apr 2017 |        EB | TL: 395mm WC:',
            '|       87 | A-1445 |        anas clypeata |       M |  G. Webber |                               n/a |                     A. Zack |     23 Oct 2013 |  26 Apr 2017 |        EB | TL: 395mm WC:']
    size = [800, 600]
    obj_main_frame = tk.Tk()
    data_frame = tk.Frame(obj_main_frame, width=size[0], height=size[1])
    scrollbar_y = tk.Scrollbar(obj_main_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
    scrollbar_x = tk.Scrollbar(obj_main_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
    data_scrollable = tk.Listbox(data_frame, font=tkFont.Font(family="Courier", size=10), selectbackground="gray", selectmode=tk.SINGLE, width=150, yscrollcommand=scrollbar_y.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbar_x.set)
    scrollbar_y.config(command=data_scrollable.yview)
    scrollbar_x.config(command=data_scrollable.xview)
    obj_main_frame.grid()
    data_frame.grid_propagate(0)
    data_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    scrollbar_x.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
    scrollbar_y.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
    data_scrollable.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    for i, datum in enumerate(data):
        data_scrollable.insert(tk.END, datum)

    obj_main_frame.mainloop()
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    view()
```

Answer (score 1):

You made 2 mistakes in your alignment.

- First, you should remove the `width` argument when defining your listbox, so that it can adjust to the size of its parent:

  ```
  data_scrollable = tk.Listbox(data_frame, 
                               font=tkFont.Font(family="Courier", size=10),
                               selectbackground="gray", selectmode=tk.SINGLE,
                               yscrollcommand=scrollbar_y.set,
                               xscrollcommand=scrollbar_x.set)
  ```
- Second, after aligning the listbox in its frame, you must give non-zero weights to the corresponding row and column, to allow the listbox to expand:

  ```
  data_scrollable.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
  data_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
  data_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
  ```

See: [Tkinter Grid Manager documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)